# Why the for...in statement returns both methods and properties?

Tags: javascript

As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) says, the for...in statement has access to all properties (and values) related to an object.

I am not sure about why are methods also listed with this statement: if I loop on the `document` object I get not only the properties list related to it, but also the methods such as prompt() or focus()

Why are these methods named as "properties" on all documentation related to the for...in loop?

Comment: Because methods are properties?

Comment: Because in javascript an object is a collection of `name : value` pairs and the `value` can be a function, this is how you get a method. I do not think that `for...in` is meant to be used on things like `document`

Comment: @GerardoFurtado a better question is, why are `prompt` and `focus` enumerable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because methods are also properties, just with the type of `function`.

See for yourself:

```
for (var prop in document) {
    console.log("document." + prop + " = " + document[prop], typeof(document[prop]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this link, i think it will be helpful:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229054(v=vs.100).aspx...

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a deep look at this :)